# How to enable 'wget' to download the whole content of HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, linux, cgi, wget

I have a  [site](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/Research/Acembly/av.cgi?db=mouse&c=gene&a=fiche&l=2610008E11Rik) which I want to download using Unix `wget`. 
If you look at the source code and content of the file it contain section called SUMMARY.
However after issuing a wget command like this:

```
wget   -O downdloadedtext.txt  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/Research/Acembly/av.cgi?db=mouse&c=gene&a=fiche&l=2610008E11Rik
```

The content of the `downdloadedtext.txt` is incomplete and different with the source code
of that site. For example it doesn't contain SUMMARY section. Is there a correct way to obtain the full content correctly?

The reason I ask this because I want to automate the download from different values in that HTML.

Comment: I don't understand. What differences are there in the source code? And what does Javascript have to do with it?

Comment: @Pekka: The body which contain javascript doesn't get downloaded. Please try and see.

Comment: I don't have wget handy right now (on a windows machine). Is the actual *body* different or are the js files not getting downloaded?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put the link inside quotes:

```
 wget -O downdloadedtext.txt  'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/Research/Acembly/av.cgi?db=mouse&c=gene&a=fiche&l=2610008E11Rik'
```

This is because the & has a special meaning and will split the command into multiple commands.

Answer (score 3):

The `&` character has special meaning in shells. Quote the URI so you actually request the URI you want to request.

Comment: @DD: How to quote? I tried "\&l=2610008E11Rik" but failed still.

Comment: Try `&amp;` instead of the `&`.

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks but still no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-p` (`--page-prerequisites`) flag to tell `wget` to retrieve linked resources. From `man wget`:

> This option causes Wget to download all the files that are necessary to properly display a given HTML page.  This includes such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.

You might also look at the `--follow-tags` option, which lets you limit that process:

> Wget has an internal table of HTML tag / attribute pairs that it considers when looking for linked documents during a recursive retrieval.  If a user wants only a subset of those tags to be considered, however, he or she should be specify such tags in a comma-separated list with this option.

Comment: @TJC: That won't do. I don't want to get content of the linked source. I just want to get the complete content of that very site.

Comment: @neversaint I think you mean "page", not "site"