# How can i export html to file via command line with FireFox

Tags: firefox, command-line

So the question explains itself very good.

Is there a console command line to save the html with firefox?

Thanks.

Comment: The html is already a file, where would you want to save the file to and what would you do to it?

Comment: i want to save what the firefox gets for the html. That's because some pages are generated dinamically with js and a simple wget or another thing did not work.

Comment: Hmm, it seems strange that wget wouldn't work. Thje fact the page is dynamic is irrelevant, its served as html.

Comment: i've doubts with the js that render html text inside... wget does not have a javascript engine to do it.

Comment: Show us the command line you're using. This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636286/how-to-enable-wget-to-download-the-whole-content-of-html-with-javascript suggests seems to have alot of answer

Comment: Thanks David, but the problem with the js still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pup`](https://github.com/EricChiang/pup). Unlike [automate-save-page-as](https://github.com/abiyani/automate-save-page-as), [`pup`](https://github.com/EricChiang/pup) doesn't save the raw HTML, but outputs the parsed HTML.

Answer (score 18):

There is no way to ask Firefox to save a page via command line (as of May 2015). There is, however, a script that can automate the process of launching Firefox, saving the page, quitting Firefox.

https://github.com/abiyani/automate-save-page-as

From the README file:

> A quick hack for when wget doesn't cut it.
>
> tl;dr Perform browser's "Save page as" (Ctrl+S) operation from command line without manual intervention
>
> This small bash script simulates a sequence of key presses which opens a given url in the browser, save the page (Ctrl+S), and close the browser tab/window (Ctrl+F4).
>
> ```
> # Use Firefox to open a web-page and save it in /tmp
> # (the default name for the file (Page title) is used)
> $ ./save_page_as "www.example.com" --browser "firefox" --destination "/tmp"
> ```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks. :)

Comment: Too bad this just saves the HTML, not Firefox's Gecko's webengine rendered HTML (Inspector's "[Copy Outer HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML#Copy%20Outer%20HTML)").

Comment: @Geremia no it saves the rendered HTML, you just need to save as "webpage, complete"

Comment: An update when this works with Wayland would be nice :)

Answer (score 12):

The suggestion to use wget wouldn't handle the case where access to the content requires special login or other authentication that requires some user action from inside the browser (e.g. storing the authentication results for example in firefox's cert8.db or keys.db or signons.sqlite or even in locatsore.rdf).  wget --load-cookies using the firefox cookies may not work, if authentication is done via javascript inside the web page loaded.

So the user want some way to run firefox like so:

```
firefox "<some-url-with-complex-authentication>" -save-to-folder ./somewhere
```

(and firefox exits when it has finished saving the URL it fetched).
Yes, it's heavy, but if you can view the page in a browser but not via wget or similar, then there doesn't currently seem to be any way to do it that could be used from the command line.

However, it may simply be that the user did not export the freshest cookies file from FF so that it could be loaded by wget --load-cookies, since to create a wget-compatible (netscape style) cookies file requires:
1) installing a plugin like Export Cookies
2) exporting the cookies.txt file for wget to use.

Comment: Checked August 2018, this solution does not work anymore. The cmd will just open Firefox Browser, with the intended URL. Nothing else happends.

Comment: As stated by @weefwefwqg3 it looks like `-save-to-folder` hasn't worked since at least Firefox 27 (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984910 ).

Comment: I found a script to replace this: https://github.com/abiyani/automate-save-page-as (It launches Firefox with the desired URL and sends "fake" keystrokes (with `xdotool`, so linux only), to trigger the "Save page as" action).

Answer (score 2):

I use this way on Windows with PowerShell:

```
[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("Firefox","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429745/how-can-i-export-html-to-file-via-command-line-with-firefox")
Sleep 2;

$obj_Shell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$obj_Shell.AppActivate('Firefox');
Sleep 1;

$obj_Shell.SendKeys("^(s)");
Sleep 3;

$obj_Shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");

Select-String -Path $env:USERPROFILE + "\Downloads\how-can-i-export-html-to-file-via-command-line-with-firefox.html"
```